# CSS Break line when content overflows

Tags: css, html, width, overflow, line

I am wondering how to break a line with css when content reaches the width of a div, as I am making a blogging system.
 
 -Matthew

Comment: For the love of god, CODE PELASE!

Answer (score 2):

Use CSS property `word-wrap: break-word`.